# Google Cloud Messaging: I have given my Android app the necessary permissions but it still gives an error when registering the device

Tags: android, permissions, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to develop an application that can receive push notifications from GCM. I have given the following permissions in my Android Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<permission android:name="com.example.notifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.notifications.persmission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

I have also defined the following BroadcastReceiver in the Manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.notifications" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I have also implemented a GCMIntentService with the necessary method overrides, including an onRegistered method.

However, I receive the following error in Logcat when the GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId method is called:

```
05-31 15:13:19.359: W/ActivityManager(62): Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION cat=[com.example.notifications] (has extras) } to com.example.notifications requires com.example.notifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE due to sender com.google.android.gsf (uid 10013)
```

It seems to be saying that the app requires the com.example.notifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE permssion although it has already been provided in the manifest.

Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.notifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

With.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.notifications.persmission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

The issue is

```
permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

The official gcm tutorial is given here plese go through this to avoid future issues
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
persmission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

Should be:

```
permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```